# Nightmare JS will not open file dialog

Tags: dialog, electron, nightmare

If I click the button manually, or if I run `.click()` in the console, the *open file* dialog pops up in the Electron browser, and works fine.

However if I run it automatically by nightmare, the window pop up does not appear.

I have tried clicking in within evaluate, giving the element an `id`, to be sure I am interacting with the element, and then clicking the `ID` with nightmare

```
var clickUpload = await nightmare.evaluate(function (selector) {

    document.querySelector(selector).id="theElement";

    return "Element Given ID";
}, ".camera")


 await nightmare.wait(2000);
     nightmare.upload("#theElement","./pic.jpeg")
nightmare.click("#theElement")
```